# np.timedelta - Unit M is not supported error after updating packages version

Tags: pandas, numpy, datetime

The following code worked fine:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'from_date': ['01-10-2003', '15-12-2004', '01-08-2012', '09-07-2001'],
                  'to_date': ['01-11-2003', '15-12-2006', '01-09-2012', '09-12-2001']})
df['from_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['from_date'], format='%d-%m-%Y')
df['to_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['to_date'], format='%d-%m-%Y')
df['Months'] = (df['to_date']-df['from_date'])/np.timedelta64(1, 'M')
df
```

After packages update it gives the following error:

```
ValueError: Unit M is not supported. Only unambiguous timedelta values durations are supported. Allowed units are 'W', 'D', 'h', 'm', 's', 'ms', 'us', 'ns'
```

Pandas = 2.1.4, Numpy = 1.26.2

How can I now calculate month difference between two dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to compute an exact difference, convert [`to_period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html):

```
df['Months_period'] = (df['to_date'].dt.to_period('M')
                       .sub(df['from_date'].dt.to_period('M'))
                       .apply(lambda x: x.n)
                      )
```

Output (compared to using 30 days an approximation for a month):

```
   from_date    to_date  Months_30D  Months_period
0 2003-10-01 2003-11-01    1.033333              1
1 2004-12-15 2006-12-15   24.333333             24
2 2012-08-01 2012-09-01    1.033333              1
3 2001-07-09 2001-12-09    5.100000              5
4 2000-01-01 2023-01-01  280.033333            276
```

Comment: I was about to post `df.apply(lambda s: s.dt.to_period("M").diff()["to_date"].n, axis=1)` ;)

Comment: @Timeless I always try to avoid `apply` with `axis=1`. Also using `diff` here is a cool trick but relies on having no other column and the correct order ;)

Comment: Got you ;) Just to be sure we select to correct cols/order, `df[["from_date", "to_date"]].apply`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently 'M' in `np.timedelta64(1, 'M')` does not work anymore.
One can use 'D' days difference and divide by 30:

```
df['Months'] = (df['to_date']-df['from_date'])/np.timedelta64(1, 'D') / 30
```

or can use %:

```
df['Months'] = (df['to_date']-df['from_date'])/np.timedelta64(1, 'D') % 30
```

Comment: That's however quickly giving incorrect results. Try for example to compute the difference between 2000-01-01 and 2023-01-01 (23*12 = 276 months), this will give you 280 months instead.

Comment: Thanks. For my purpose it was ok - but you are right that for high differences your solution is better. Thanks!